# How to have code executed on termination

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, finally

I want a part of my code to only execute when I manually stop the program (like pressing stop button in `pycharm`). I thought finally statement could do it for me. Like this:

```
try:
   do_sth()
finally:
   print("you stopped the program")
```

but it doesn't work. I tried both finally and except but none of them worked. I thought when we stopped the program from running, a `keyboard_intrrupt` error occurred so finally must have worked.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `atexit` library.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html):

> The atexit module defines functions to register and unregister cleanup functions. Functions thus registered are automatically executed upon normal interpreter termination.

This can be implemented like so:

```
#Rest of program...

def before_termination():
    #Do something...

import atexit    
atexit.register(before_termination)
```

However this is only called during normal program termination, not if keyboard interrupt occurs.

Comment: When i use this, I don't need to call the function somewhere in my code?

Comment: Thank you very very much

Comment: @aref Should probably mention that `atexit` is only called during normal program termination, not when you keyboard interrupt/stop in pycharm.

Comment: @dheiberg Thank you, I've added that to the answer :)